# How can I use quotation marks like brackets in math mode?

Tags: math-mode, brackets, text, delimiters

I'd like to enclose some content in quotation marks in math mode. The content is text, so I put it as a parameter to `\text` from amsmath.

```
S = \text{“some text”}
```

But the quotation marks aren't part of the content of S, so I'd like to not include them in the `\text` tag. Ideally, the quotation marks would function as delimiters like brackets, so it would be this:

```
S = \left“ \text{some text} \right”
```

That would allow also parity checks, using them with things other than text, and maybe automatic sizing and positioning.

How can I do something like that? I mean defining custom bracket-like delimiters or an other tool for setting text strings in math mode.

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of resizing you have in mind.

Comment: quotation marks are normally considered text not math so `\text{“some text”}` looks like the expected markup to me.  `\left\right` looks wrong, you could use `\mathopen` \mathclose` like non-stretchy () but text seems more natural. You can only use `\left` with characters that are set up in the font as variable sized, and that won't be the case with delimiters.

Comment: I think it’s not unreasonable to ask for automatic positioning when we are dealing with large math structures. Obviously for the closing quotation marks, you can do `{...}''`. I’m not quite sure what to do about the opening marks. Maybe rotating `\prime` and doing `\vphantom{...}^{\rotatedprime\rotatedprime}{...}''`?

Comment: @Gaussler but `{...}''` in math will make a double superscript prime not a close quote, they don't really look that similar.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Then suggest a way to fix this. `:-)`

Comment: @Gaussler I'd like to use not primes but quotation marks, like what I used in the question, which are `“` and `”`. [Having these characters in the code literally] is fine. (not “… [literally is fine].”)

Comment: I have just noticed that having the characters `“` and `”` just outside of `\text` (`“\text{some text}”`) looks identical to when they are inside it, so I may use that. I don't know why I didn't try it earlier; maybe because I tried something similar and it produced incorrect typesetting. Is having these characters loosely in math mode safe? (Can't It cause something like spacing issues in some cases?)

Comment: There are various forms of quotes.  In ASCII, `'` will take on the form of a prime in math.  However, unicode quotations exist, such as  `“` and `”`, which should not be adversely affected by the presence of a math environment.  However, you have to make sure your font supports their rendering.

Answer (score 1):

#### New Solution

I defined a command `\mathquote{...}` that inserts quotation marks depending on the vertical size of its content.

##### Code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\newlength{\mqheight}
\newlength{\mqnormalheight}
\settoheight{\mqnormalheight}{\hbox{gM}}%
\newcommand{\mathquote}[1]{%
    \settoheight{\mqheight}{\hbox{\ensuremath{#1}}}%
    \addtolength{\mqheight}{-\mqnormalheight}%
    \text{\raisebox{\the\mqheight}{``}}%
    #1%
    \text{\raisebox{\the\mqheight}{''}}%
    %\qquad\text{(raise quotes by: \the\mqheight)}% (info)
}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
    a &= \mathquote{\sum\limits_{i=1}^N i}\\
    b &= \mathquote{\int\limits_{a}^{b} x^2 dx}\\
    c &= \mathquote{\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^n i\right) + x}\\
    d &= \mathquote{g + B}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

##### Result

[image]

#### Old Solution

Your question is not completely clear to me, but to get automatic parity check you can use the package `csquotes` and its command `\enquote{...}`, which is also useful for normal text and different languages.

In this case (language = default = english) the result is the same as typing `“` and `”`.

##### Code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
    a &= \text{“some text”}\\
    b &= \text{\enquote{some text}}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

##### Result

[image]

Comment: `\enquote` doesn't work in math mode, and I want to have the quotation marks outside of the `\text` tag because they aren't a part of the text string. Also, ideally, I'd like to be able to use the quotes with things other than text strings, but that isn't necessary.

Comment: I don't understand the need why the quotes should not be inside the text command. How would the result be different if the quotes were outside? This should be explained in more detail in the question, possibly with a concrete example and an image of the desired result.

Comment: @dexteritas -- the OP says (in a comment) that something like an integral sign might be wanted inside the quoted material, and the (relatively low) vertical position of the quotation marks would look silly in that case.  Unfortunately, I don't have any good suggestions for raising them to an appropriate height.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thanks for the explanation. I added a new solution.